# How to call functions/procedures from Oracle Database using Kotlin Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

So I've been using Kotlin with Spring Boot for quite some times and I recently found "Ktor" and "Exposed"

And I decided to give it a try, still stuck with the function calling since we (developers) have functions and/or stored procedures on the Oracle Database to call

So as the topic says, using Exposed, how to call functions and/or procedures?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always can execute any "raw" sqls with `Transaction.exec` function ([faq](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-is-it-possible-to-use-native-sql--sql-as-a-string)), but also it's possible to define your own functions to use it later in Exposed DSL ([wiki](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/Functions#custom-functions))

Comment: I'm still trying the DSL, but it's quite confusing since I've always use Spring JDBC + Native/Raw SQL all the time (I've never use ORM before). Still wondering if I can call DB's functions by DSL (There are functions made by my co-workers and he stored it on DB, not the code itself) Will use the 'Transaction.exec' if I can't make DSL to work. Many thanks!

Comment: OK, I finally got it, many thanks!